# Embedding equation labels inside figures/graphics?

Tags: graphics, equations, cross-referencing

One thing I would really like to do (for the purposes of a thesis) is to embed equation references/tags inside images, so that I can reference the equations outside of the image.

To give you an idea, I would like to achieve something like the following:

[image]

However, I would like the equation numbers to be *dynamic*, that is, to change depending on the other equations in the document in which the graphic is embedded. I used GeoGebra to create this picture, but unfortunately I don't think this supports equation references (even though it is possible to export the picutre in TiKZ format, I think).

I have been told that it is much better practice for my thesis to create diagrams which summarise the equations being solved, but the downside of this is that the referencing is not necessarily straightforward. For example, I would like to be able to refer to the equations inside the graphic, rather than saying "Equation (1) from Figure XX".

Has anyone figured out a way to do this? If so, what strategy did you use?

Comment: You could could use minipages and place an image on the left had side and use latex to write the equations of the right hand side.

Comment: I understand - in the example shown above I gather this would be a sensible solution. But what about more generally (where the labels can be anywhere inside the graphic)?

Comment: from Geogebra, it is possible to export to Tikz. The downside is that the generated code is quite static (doesn't use nodes as plotting variables). I can put references to equations inside the tikzpicture. they would update with your equations. Does this help?

Comment: I don't know about GeoGebra but it is certainly possible to either use directly `align` or similar environments from `amsmath` in a node (though you will need to set a `text width`) or just use the `equation` counter directly. You will, of course, place `\label`s to later refer to them.

Comment: You can overprint an image using TikZ or package `overpic` and something like `\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)` to print the faked tag.

Comment: @anis Do you mean by modifying the TikZ code to add these nodes manually? When I edit the equations in my GeoGebra figure to incorporate labels, the equation completely vanishes. This leads me to believe that GeoGebra's LaTeX renderer is not compatible with equation labels/references.

Comment: I will post an answer and you tell me if it fits your criterion. brb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Export to `tikz`:

[image]

The resulting code is an absolute horror. But it does compile to what was displayed (there might be some edge cases).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [color=cqcqcq,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt, xstep=1.0cm,ystep=1.0cm] (0,-10) grid (10,0);
\draw[->,color=black] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x in {,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0,-10) -- (0,0);
\foreach \y in {-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\clip(0,-10) rectangle (10,0);
\fill[line width=1.2pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.1] (9.2,-2.18) -- (2.56,-2.12) -- (5.08,-5.16) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzttqq] (9.2,-2.18)-- (2.56,-2.12);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzttqq] (2.56,-2.12)-- (5.08,-5.16);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzttqq] (5.08,-5.16)-- (9.2,-2.18);
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=qqqqff] (9.2,-2.18) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (9.36,-1.92) node {$A$};
\fill [color=qqqqff] (2.56,-2.12) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (2.72,-1.86) node {$B$};
\fill [color=qqqqff] (5.08,-5.16) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (5.24,-4.9) node {$C$};
\draw[color=zzttqq] (7.4,-3.78) node {$b$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

2. add a node and the desired equation.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    
    \definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0}
    \definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
    \definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \draw [color=cqcqcq,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt, xstep=1.0cm,ystep=1.0cm] (0,-10) grid (10,0);
    \draw[->,color=black] (0,0) -- (10,0);
    \foreach \x in {,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    \draw[->,color=black] (0,-10) -- (0,0);
    \foreach \y in {-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1}
    \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
    \draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
    \clip(0,-10) rectangle (10,0);
    \fill[line width=1.2pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.1] (9.2,-2.18) -- (2.56,-2.12) -- (5.08,-5.16) -- cycle;
    \draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzttqq] (9.2,-2.18)-- (2.56,-2.12);
    \draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzttqq] (2.56,-2.12)-- (5.08,-5.16);
    \draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzttqq] (5.08,-5.16)-- (9.2,-2.18);
    \begin{scriptsize}
    \fill [color=qqqqff] (9.2,-2.18) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=qqqqff] (9.36,-1.92) node {$A$};
    \fill [color=qqqqff] (2.56,-2.12) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=qqqqff] (2.72,-1.86) node {$B$};
    \fill [color=qqqqff] (5.08,-5.16) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=qqqqff] (5.24,-4.9) node {$C$};
    \draw[color=zzttqq] (7.4,-3.78) node {$b$};
    \end{scriptsize}
    
    % adding some reference to some equation
    \node at (8,-5){Applying equation \ref{eq-2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
    According to the right Pythagorean theorem:
\begin{equation}\label{eq-1}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
    
According to the wrong Pythagorean theorem:
    \begin{equation}\label{eq-2}
    a + b = c
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Result:

[image: result]

### EDIT:

Request: write the equation but don't display it, yet keep it referenced.

Answer: use the `textpos` package and wrap your equation in a `textblock` environment:

```
%\usepackage{textpos} <--- in the preambule
According to the wrong Pythagorean theorem:
\begin{textblock}{width}(X_offset, Y_offset)
\begin{equation}\label{eq-2}
    a + b = c
\end{equation}
\end{textblock}
```

You can use `(X_offset, Y_offset)` to "yeet" the equation out of the paper, for e.g. `(10,10)`.

### Result:

The equation can't be found in the pdf, but it is written in the LaTeX source.

[image]

Comment: Does this corresponds to what you wanted? @OGBond

Comment: A better workflow should be to put directly placeholders inside `GeoGebra` via texts before the export to `TikZ`.

Comment: @anis Thank you so much - I will take a look and get back to you.

Comment: it produces this `\draw (9.22,-5.24) node[anchor=north west] {place holder text};` which isn't appealing to me tbh.

Comment: @projetmbc I completely agree. However, I think GeoGebra would be reticent to adding this feature. I contacted them directly about LaTeX/TiKZ functionality and unfortunately it isn't currently being supported. I think this is probably because GeoGebra is primarily aimed at educators (who don't necessarily need to be able to use LaTeX) rather than academic mathematicians/scientists. That said, the code for GeoGebra is open-source, so somebody with more of a software development background could modify the code to include equation referencing - sadly I don't think I have time to do this...

Comment: @anis I see what you've done. You've listed the equations separately after the TiKZ picture, and given those the references, rather then adding the references to the equations in the picture in the first instance. This works just as well for my purposes. What if I wanted to hide the equations after the tikzpicture, so that effectively the only place the reference exists is within the tikzpicture when the document is processed?

Comment: Wait, I am not fully understanding it. in my example, the wrong theorem is referenced inside the tikzpicture. Where else would you get the equation from? @OGBond

Comment: @OGBond, as weird as your request is, I have found a way to hack it and obtain a reference to an equation that can't be found in the document, yet can be referenced correctly.

Comment: @anis I don't mean to completely get rid of the equations you are referencing, but keep them in the LaTeX source code but without showing them in the document. In doing so, I want to effectively only state the equations once (in the diagram) and circumvent the need to list them all out in the text afterwards. I still want the equations to be stored in the LaTeX document, but just not displayed. Does this make more sense?

Comment: you can grab any equation and put anywhere, the `\ref{}` inside the tikz will find it. There is a way to achieve what you are describing, let me make an edit. @OGBond, check the edit.

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit confused about the other answer but going on

> embed equation references/tags inside images, so that I can reference the equations outside of the image

Yes, this is possible but not that straight forward.

The numbered displaymath environments need a line width which is easily achieved in TikZ by setting a `text width` but you need to choose a sensible text width on your own. This will also place the equation number inside the node.

I've added a node with `aligned` in the example below where `\tagoutside` produces another column where the equation number is set left-aligned (as in your picture but not as with `amsmath` usually).

The `\rlap` and the measurements inside it make sure that the equation number is actually outside the node but this has the side effect that the equation numbers are also outside of the bounding box of the TikZ picture.

There probably is a more sophisticated solution with a `tikzmark` approach but for simple equations (and a simple rectangular node) this might be enough.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\tagoutside[1]{
  &\kern-\alignsep@
    \rlap{% no math content → no mathrlap necessary
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep})}%
      \kern\pgfutil@tempdima
      \refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}%
      \quad\tagform@\theequation
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some formulas:
\begin{align}
    c^2 &= a^2 + b^2 \label{tri} \\
    E   &= mc^2      \label{albert}
\end{align}

Now a tikzpicture (inside a float):
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=3cm, draw, drop shadow, fill=white] {
  \vspace{-\topskip}
  \begin{align}
    c^2 &= a^2 + b^2 \label{tikz-tri} \\
    E   &= mc^2      \label{tikz-albert}
  \end{align}
};
\node[draw, drop shadow, fill=white] at (4,0) {$
  \begin{aligned}
    c^2 &= a^2 + b^2 \tagoutside{tikzed-tri} \\
    E   &= mc^2      \tagoutside{tikzed-albert}
  \end{aligned}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

Now another set of formulas:
\begin{align}
    c^2 &= a^2 + b^2 \label{tri*} \\
    E   &= mc^2      \label{albert*}
\end{align}

Equations
\eqref{tri}        \eqref{albert}
\eqref{tikz-tri}   \eqref{tikz-albert}
\eqref{tikzed-tri} \eqref{tikzed-albert}
\eqref{tri*}       \eqref{albert*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I like this approach. I didn't know that align environment was allowed in tikz node